# excel - searching in tables located in different sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to use vlookup function to find value in table located in another sheet.
BUT I want to read sheet name from one cell.
I tried:

> VLOOKUP(D8,INDIRECT($B$4&"!$A:$B",FALSE),2,FALSE)

(where B4 contains sheet name)
but it doesn't work.

How I should use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

> =VLOOKUP(D8,INDIRECT("'" & $B$4 & "'!$A:$B"),2,FALSE)

it should also work with spaces in the sheet name